# Find intersection point of two distributions in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm graphing distributions of predicted probabilities within two classes and am interested in finding the point where the two distribution peaks intersect (around .25 in the image below).

My code for the graph is:

```
twoway kdensity Predicted if conflict==0, lcolor(black) || kdensity Predicted   if conflict==1, lcolor(green)
```

[image]
Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: How do predicted probabilities have values of about 2 or -0.25? Something is wrong or inappropriate there.

Comment: Right, it's because I'm performing a geographically weighted regression in ArcMap and it only has the capacity to perform an LPM. I'm only using the predicted probabilities to perform classification, which is why I'm looking to understand how to find a meaningful cut-off point with which to separate the distributions.

Comment: I don't follow. Probabilities as I understand them are on a 0 to 1 scale. So, either these are not probabilities, or they are transforms of probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
kdensity yourvar, generate(newvar_x newvar_d)
```

which will give you the approximation points. with this you can find the approximate intersection point.

Comment: This is correct; I add a statistical warning to the OP that such intersections are usually **highly sensitive to the kernel type and width you choose**. There is no magic to the default choices. Finding where the quantile functions cross, if they do, would be a less sensitive choice. What's obvious in your example graph is that you have a lumpy distribution with outliers.

Comment: It's really the shift of quantile functions that would be the first focus of concern if you follow my advice.